# How do Maven and Fortify determine how much memory to use?

Tags: java, maven, fortify

I am using the Fortify SCA plugin with Maven 3.2.1 to scan a pretty large Java webapp.

1. I have a custom .bat file that sets up my all my environment variables and makes a call to mvn.bat to start the scan.
2. Then mvn.bat reads my pom.xml and finds the custom profiles for clean, translate, and scan and then calls sourceanalyzer.

The trouble is, it never seems like sourceanalyzer uses the full amount of memory that I grant it in either the custom bat file or the pom file.  This machine has 16GB of RAM, and when the scan is done 18-20 hours later it will print "memory used: 317 MB" and the report has a bunch of Out of Memory warnings. This machine is doing nothing besides this scan, and while it's running the Task Manager shows that something is using a bunch of memory.

The error message is "Scan progress is slowing due to JVM garbage collection."

My MAVEN_OPTS:

- -Xmx4096m
- -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
- -Dfortify.sca.64bit=true
- -Dfortify.sca.Xmx=8000m
- -DskipTests=true
- -Dfortify.sca.verbose=true

I need to figure out how to both speed this scan up and remove the memory warnings.

Thanks

Comment: Based on the docs of fortify the fortify plugin calls a new JVM as far as i know and you have to configure the fortify maven plugin with an appropriate parameter to use 4-6 GiB memory. MAVEN_OPTS will only configure for Maven itself but not for a forked JVM.

Comment: I have configured the plugin with maxHeap 8000M and it still only uses ~300M.  Where else could I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the SCA memory variable option. Set:

SCA_VM_OPTS=-Xmx8000M

You can also try posting Fortify issues to their online forum at https://protect724.hp.com. The support group monitors those forums.